# How to stretch a line across the entire page width

Tags: graphics

I would like to stretch a black line across the entire page width. MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=.0in}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\begin{document}

\makebox[10in][c]{\xrfill{10pt}}

\end{document}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to get the box to begin at the left edge of the page - instead it begins at the left margin, as shown here:
[image: marginproblem]

Any assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work if the left/right margins are symmetric.  If not, one could always increase the width of the `\rule` to compensate.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=.0in}
\begin{document}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{10pt}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use different tools for this: `atbegshi` seems to be the best one for this application.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\AtBeginShipoutNext{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    \put(0,0){\vrule width \paperwidth height 0pt depth 10pt}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{A. Uthor}

\maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

If you want the band on all pages, use `\AtBeginShipout` instead of `\AtBeginShipoutNext`.

[image]

Comment: A similar output can be achieved with [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic).

Comment: @Werner Yes, but I find `atbegshi` easier.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution with TikZ. You have to compile *twice* to get it right.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\UpperPageRule{%
  \tikz [remember picture,overlay]%
  \fill (current page.north west) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,-10pt);%
}
\begin{document}
\UpperPageRule
\section{First Page}
\newpage
\UpperPageRule
\section{Second Page}
\end{document}
```

[image]